# A3 indesign file, wanting to export to A4 PDF how?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, portfolio

I'm sure this can be done, just cant figure out how. I'm needing to export my portfolio as a pdf but my indesign document is a3, i see no option to chose the size.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to take your A3 indesign document and place it inside an A4 document.

1. Open a new document and set it's size to A4
2. Draw a Rectangle or Rectangle Frame over your whole artboard (consider allowing for bleed if you need it)
3. CMD/Ctrl + D and select your A3 InDesign file and place it into the Rectangle
4. Fit the placed A3 file into rectangle, making sure not to distort it
5. Export your PDF as you would normally

*Alternatively, you can export the A3 document as an A3 PDF and insert this at stage 3.*

In(Design)ception ;)

Comment: Is there any fast way to do this for a many many page document?

Comment: I used [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) to do it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size of a document on export, you'll need to change the document size and then export it.

Choose: File->Document Setup (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and change the size there.

[image]

Then you'll be able to export it as a PDF.

Comment: ah thats sucks, my whole document would then need resizing for a4. Unless there is a way to scale everything down

Comment: You could place your current document into a new document that is a4 size. You'll be able to scale each page down when placing it.

Answer (score 1):

Open a new A4 document. 
In the A3 document "Select All" and "Copy" 
Go to the A4 and "Paste"
Then incrementally re size all of the elements together until you get the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

You can press Page tool (Shift+P), which is normally the third icon under the white arrow into the Tool Bar. Make sure that all the layers into the document are unlocked, then in the Liquid Page Rule press Scale, then press Ctrl+A to select the pages and give the size of A4. It automatically scale the content to A4.

Answer (score 1):

InDesign now has an Adjust Layout tool.

Press Alt+Shift+P, select your page size and you're good to go!

(This question is 8 years old but still ranks well on Google haha)